# How can I add navigation links below WordPress posts using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a PHP/WordPress-based website and would like to add 3 navigation links (one previous link and 2 next links) below each post of a custom post type. The links should look like this:

[prev] [next] [next]

My current code is below, but it is not working at the moment. How can I get this code to display the desired links?

```
$currentID = get_the_ID();

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'guides' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'         => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    =>true,
    'post__not_in'           => array($currentID)
);

$guides_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $guides_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="grid-container nxt-article">';
    echo '<div class="nxt-article-heading"><h2>Next article</h2></div>';
    while ( $guides_query->have_posts() ) {
        $guides_query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="nxt-article-box"><div class="nxt-article-box-shadow">';
        echo '<a class="nxt-article-link" href="'.get_the_permalink().'"></a>';
        $gear_category = get_field('gear_category', $products->ID);
        if ($gear_category) :
            echo '<div class="g_pre_title" style="color:#fff;position:absolute;left:30px;top:25px;">'.$gear_category[0].'</div>';
        endif;      

        echo '<div>';

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'post_grid_image' );
        }       
        echo '</div><div style="padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;"><div class="nxt-article-box-title">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
        $intro_section = get_field('introduction_section', $post->ID);
        if( $intro_section ) :
            echo '<div class="pg_excerpt" style="height:85px;overflow:hidden;">'.wp_trim_words( $intro_section['wysiwyg'], 32, '...' ).'</div>';
        endif;
        echo '</div></div></div>';
    }
    echo '<div style="text-align:center;"><a class="ml_button_style" href="">Show ALL GUIDES</a></div>';
    echo '</div>';
} else {
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Clarified question and removed fluff/redundancy

Comment: Clarified title

Comment: Please give a more specific explanation of the current state of your code. For example, list any error messages you are getting and add comments to explain what you are expecting each part of the code to do.